# ¿Como usar un websocket en un servidor compartido?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, websocket

Tengo una duda con respecto a la tecnología websocket, mi pregunta es, **¿puedo utilizar websocket en un servidor de hosting compartido?**

Al parecer creo que necesito un puerto que no se utilice en otra parte, y creo que el hosting compartido no es el indicado.

Tendría que utilizar un VPS (Servidor Privado).

Comment: Al parecer creo que necesito un puerto que no se utilice en otra parte, y creo que el hosting compartido no es el indicado.

Comment: Se pueden servir websockets en los puertos estándar HTTP (80 y 443). Si tu servidor compartido soporta websockets y se los pasa a tu aplicación es una pregunta para tu proveedor :) https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: Hice una consulta con un proveedor de servicios de hosting (dónde tengo un sitio) y, como la oferta es similar en caso todos te puede servir: [Socket Connections](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/socket-connections) Es un buen indicador de que **los hostings compartidos no soportan websockets** *imagino que no sea buen negocio*